# -in operator not working in version 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following line of code that works in powershell 3.0

```
$Type = "DD"
if ($Type -in "AA","BB","CC") {Write-Host  "Type = $Type" -ForegroundColor Yellow }
```

However I got error when run it with PowerShell 2.0

```
- : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Why is that so? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-in` is not present in 2.0. You need to use [`-contains`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) instead (and the respective foils `-notin` / `-notcontains` ). Same functionality but just a little less intuitive. That is one of the reasons `-in` was introduced.

```
if ("AA","BB","CC" -contains $Type){"Do Stuff"}
```

While the documentation linked is for 3.0 and higher I don't believe the section pertaining to `-contains` is any different.

Comment: Matt, Thank you so much for the quick reply. Very much appreciate it. Cheers!